# Regular expression match and extraction string

Tags: shell, scripting, sed, awk

I have a string containing content such as "`Profile - -Server-FAILUre-tESt Exception Type - timeOverThreshold Description - High CPU eHealth Alarm ID - 1000001`"

I need to extract string after word Description and before Alarm ID. I did got some help in writing below but does not seem to work. Can some one look at this and help me. The result of ALARM_TITLE is coming blank and I do not see any issue but I am definitely missing something in the regular expression.

```
ALARM_TITLE=$(echo "$EVENTMSG" | sed "s/.*Description - \(.*\) Alarm ID.*/\1/")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/.*Description\(.*\)Alarm.*$/\1/g'
```

tested:

```
> echo "Profile - -Server-FAILUre-tESt Exception Type - timeOverThreshold Description - High CPU eHealth Alarm ID - 1000001" | sed 's/.*Description\(.*\)Alarm.*$/\1/g'
 - High CPU eHealth
```

Comment: do you mean 
ALARM_TITLE=$(echo "$EVENTMSG" | sed 's/.*Description\(.*\)Alarm.*$/\1/g')

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo $STRING | grep -oP '(?<=Description - ).*(?=Alarm ID)'
```

This uses lookahead and lookbehind assertions.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ALARM_TITLE=${EVENTMSG% Alarm ID*}
ALARM_TITLE=${ALARM_TITLE#*Description - }
```

--
edit in response to comment: then try

```
ALARM_TITLE=${EVENTMSG% eHealth Alarm ID*}
```

Comment: i tried this i think it worked alsmost but just a gap....quick one it trims and output High CPU eHealth i jsut need High CPU, so in other words eHealth Alarm ID *- should be trimmed away